# Noun/Pronoun place before gerund must be in possessive case?

Tags: gerunds, possessives

So instead of saying:

> All depends on **Ron** winning a scholarship.

we should say this:

> All depends on **Ron's** winning a scholarship.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So I should always use possessive form before a gerund?

Comment: I guess the system has auto-deleted my comment because I added it to the one auto-generated by my dup closevote. Formally speaking, as StoneyB says on the original, we *would advise you to stick to the possessive, particularly if you are in school or are in a field which demands a lot of formal writing.* But you need to understand that "winning" in your first version is ***not a gerund*** - it's a *continuous participle* verb form. And even in a formal context it would often be stretching a point to say the continuous verb form was in any sense "incorrect".